# Hot to find the PhoneGap Docs (API)?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

The Docs site from PhoneGap (http://docs.phonegap.com) gives me only a simple step-by-step guide for Noobs, but as an developer, i search for the JavaScript-API as an reasonable documentation.

I usually expect more than just some information on a documentation page. That makes Phonegap pretty unappealing.

How i can find the real documentation on the site from PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that phonegap doesn't bring much to Cordova at JS level but only in the way it is built and at few years ago to send notifications.

If you want real documentation you should turn to the cordova documentation which is also rather weak. But anyway, a complete project under cordova/phonegap includes a multitude of plugins that each have their own documentation.

### Cordova documentation : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/